# How to insert record into database using multiple if statements

Tags: database, if-statement

I'm a leaning programmer, i want to insert records into database based on what ever the value is. If the value is 1 insert into a particular column, if 2, insert into another colum and so on.
Here is the if code, but i dont know what the sql statement would be like. I'll appreciate if i can get help with this.

```
    if($dm_file_owner == 1){

        $me = $dm_file_owner;
    }

    elseif ($dm_file_owner == 2){

        $office = $dm_file_owner;
    }

    elseif ($dm_file_owner == 3){

        $department = $dm_file_owner;
    }

    elseif ($dm_file_owner == 4){

        $directorate = $dm_file_owner;

    }
```

If $dm_file_owmer is quals to 1 it inserts into column me, if 2 if inserts into column office, if 3 it inserts into column department an so on. I dont know how to write the sql code, i'll appreciate if i can be assisted.

Comment: How do you process your communication with database? Any ORM, PDO, or...?

Comment: @bluszcz im using php

Comment: I know, but I ask how do you access database. In PHP there are several ways to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just initialize all your variables and execute the SQL insert statement similar to below statement.

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name (your_column1,your_column2,your_column3,your_column4,...) VALUES ('$me','$office','$department','$directorate',...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say just write separate INSERT statements for each IF statement. Then just put the corresponding INSERT inside the IF.

If you're looking for the exact INSERT needed, as blueszc already stated, we would need more information about how you're connecting to your database. Considering the fact that you're new you are probably using either [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) (which you should stay away from) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).